# NGINX Ingress + Wordpress-fpm = ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I've been searching and looking everywhere on the internet and on these forms for days to help understand how to properly setup **NGINX Ingress with Wordpress-fpm**. I'm rather new to Kubernetes and all so I've been working on setting this up to help me learn it all.

I can get it to work using the image of Wordpress that has Apache included but I rather use NGINX over Apache so this is the reason I'm trying to get it to work.

It seems that once all manifests are applied I visit localhost and I see this, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I'm guessing that Wordpress can't get the header of **X-Forwarded-Proto** that it's looking for in the wp-config.php to let it know it's behind a reverse proxy of sorts.

Below are the manifest that I'm using:

***wordpress.yml***

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-service
  namespace: wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    app: wordpress-fpm
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 9000
    protocol: TCP
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9000
    protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: wp-pv-claim
  namespace: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress-fpm
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress-fpm
  namespace: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress-fpm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress-fpm
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress-fpm
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wordpress-fpm
        image: wordpress:5.5-php7.4-fpm-alpine
        env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: maria-db-service
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_NAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: maria-db-secret
              key: db-name
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: maria-db-secret
              key: db-user
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: maria-db-secret
              key: db-user-password
        volumeMounts:
        - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/html
      volumes:
      - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wp-pv-claim
```

***ingress.yml***

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
  namespace: wordpress
data:
  SCRIPT_FILENAME: "/var/www/html/index.php"
  FASTCGI_PASS : "wordpress-fpm:9000"
  fastcgi_pass: "wordpress-fpm:9000"
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: wordpress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "FCGI"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-index: index.php
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-params-configmap: nginx-config
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - localhost
    secretName: testsecret-tls
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: wordpress-service
              port:
                name: http
```

Comment: can you describe about your project architecture a bit, where are you doing the SSL termination ? Do you have any other load balancer layers apart from nginx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Project architecture is that of a basic Wordpress setup. No other load balancers are used. Just the nginx ingress. The ssl is a self signed certificate as its a local cluster not on any cloud provider currently.

Comment: can you try testing this just at HTTP i.e. removing the tls spec from ingress rule, for testing purpose only

Comment: Same result as before.

Comment: Few questions: 1. You showed your PVC yaml, could you also share the PV configuration? 2. In your Ingress you use the rewrite annotation with `/$1` but the `path:` is empty, why? 3. Why you use `host: localhost` in your Ingress?